# Mostrar usuario a través de relación en DJango

Tags: jquery, ajax, base-de-datos, django, postgresql

Tengo en un modelo:

```
class Documento(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

En una vista leo todos los documentos y los paso a una plantilla en un contexto con el nombre "items", todo esto funciona bien, en mi plantilla:

```
{% for item in items %}
<strong>Nombre</strong>: {{ item.nombre }}
<strong>Autor</strong>: {{ item.user_set.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

El nombre del autor me sale en blanco